# php form is not sending to email

Tags: php, forms, email

I am a complete novice using php. I just need to get some information from a web form sent to my email address. I wrote this php a year ago and it worked, but I have come back to re-use it now and it is not working. Can anyone help? Its for a simple wedding RSVP form.

```
<body>
<center>
<div id="logo"><img src="../content/Logo.png" width="400" height="100" /></div>
</center>
<div id="WebsiteContainer">
<center>
<div id="Menu">
  <a href="home.html" >Home</a>
  <a href="venue.html">Venue</a>
  <a href="RSVP.php" class="loaded">RSVP</a>
  <a href="theDay.html">The Day</a>
  <a href="gifts.html">Gifts</a>
</div>
<div id="Content">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1><strong>RSVP</h1>
<p>
<center>
<p>Please use the form below to RSVP. 
  If we don't receive an RSVP we will presume that you will not be attending. If you have any requests for our DJ, please let us know in the message box below. And should you have any particular dietary needs, please let us know these too. 
  <p>

<?php

// PHP creates a $_GET variable automatically which contains any URL parameters passed. We check whether the 'submit' param
// exists using isset(), which is where our form is submitting to. If it does exist, we know the form has been submitted
// and we can process it.

if( isset( $_GET['submit'] ) ){
// Get the variables from the form
// PHP automatically creates the $_POST variable for form data, and the keys are the names we gave the form fields
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$RSVP = $_POST['RSVP'];
$guests = $_POST['ReplyFor'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Lets build the email body so it includes the name too
// PHP concatenates strings with .
$emailBody = $name . " has RSVP'd! \r\n\r\n";
$emailBody .= "Name: " . $name . "\r\n";
$emailBody .= "Email: " . $email . "\r\n";
$emailBody .= "Status: " . ( $RSVP == 'not' ) ? "Not attending" : "Attending" . "\r\n";
$emailBody .= "Guests: " . ( $guests > '1' ) ? "Themselves and " . ( $guests - 1 ) . " guest(s)" : "Themselves only" . "\r\n";
$emailBody .= "Message: " . $message . "\r\n";

// Lines in emails must be under 70 characters, so we can use PHP's wordwrap() function to add line breaks
$emailBody = wordwrap( $emailBody, 70, "\r\n" );

// Create a subject that's easy to browse in your email client
$extraSubject = ( $guests > '1' ) ? "(plus " . ( $guests - 1 ) . " guest(s) )" : "";
$subject = $name . " is " . ( ( $RSVP == 'not' ) ? ' not attending' : ' ATTENDING ' . $extraSubject );

// Send the mail using PHP's built-in mail() function
// See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
mail( mymail@somewhere.com', $subject, $emailBody );

// Now we can print out a message to them, depending on what they said
$outputMessage = ( $RSVP == 'not' ) ? "We're really sorry you can't make it!" : "We can't wait to see you at the venue in August!";
?>

<div>
    <strong>Thanks so much for RSVPing!</strong><br>
    <?=$outputMessage?><br><br>

    - Sarah &amp; Gavin     
</div>
<?
}
else 
{
?>

<form id="RSVP_Form" name="form1" method="post" action="?submit=true">
    <div>
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="30">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
        <input name="Email" type="email" id="Email" size="30">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>RSVP:</label>
        <input name="RSVP" type="radio" value='attending'>Attending
        <label></label>
        <br><input name="RSVP" type="radio" value='not'>Not Attending
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ReplyFor">Replying For:</label>
        <select name="ReplyFor" id="ReplyFor">
          <option value="1" selected="selected">Yourself Only</option>
          <option value="2">Yourself + 1 other invited guest</option>
          <option value="3">Yourself + 2 other invited guest</option>
          <option value="4">Yourself + 3 other invited guest</option>
          <option value="5">Yourself + 4 other invited guest</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="3" cols="26"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="submit">
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value=" Submit ">
    </div>
</form>
<?
}
?>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and the error would be ?

Comment: The code is long, it will be more helpful to us if you can also mention the error that you have when you run the code.

Comment: Why do you have method `POST` in your `<form>` tag and you catch the button with `GET`? Those two must match.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this line:

```
mail( mymail@somewhere.com', $subject, $emailBody );
```

You are missing one single quote before email adress.